# How to restore vcf file using without using the external app ?

Tags: android, android-intent, uri, android-file, vcf-vcard

In my application, I backup a particular contacts item as a *.vcf* file and it is  working fine, but I need to restore the contact without using an external app

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
intent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(new File(storage_path+vfile)),"text/x-vcard"); //storage 
startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: You can use this project http://code.google.com/p/vcardio/ to restore vcf with out external app.

Comment: but How to use this project ? No source code , no wiki

Comment: from the source tab you can create clone using the hg clone and get the source code.

Comment: ok. I am trying to create clone, thnx